# PySpark 1.6.1 DataFrame.write.parquet job not finishing

Tags: python-2.7, dataframe, pyspark, parquet

I have this code:

```
data_frame.write.parquet(
    '/tmp/test' , 'overwrite',
    partitionBy=None)
```

This is it's schema:

```
root
 |-- A: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- B: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- C: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- D: long (nullable = true)
 |-- E: string (nullable = true)
 |-- F: string (nullable = true)
 |-- G: string (nullable = true)
 |-- K: string (nullable = true)
 |-- L: string (nullable = true)
 |-- M: string (nullable = true)
 |-- N: long (nullable = true)
```

It get's stuck in that line and never ends (it has like a thousand rows and after two hours it doesn't finish) and if I cancel the job, the output ends as follows:

```
File "myfile.py", line <my line>, in my_method
    partitionBy=None)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 471, in parquet
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 811, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 626, in send_command
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 740, in send_command
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 430, in readline
    data = recv(1)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 225, in signal_handler
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Note: This code works with one row in that dataframe

Any ideas?

Thank you!

UPDATE--------------------

this works with a dataframe created with one json but fails with more than one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whomever may has this issue:

In my case, the problem was that the code was doing the following:

- Create a DF with the incoming data
- Transform that DF into an RDD
- Do some transformations in that RDD
- Transform again into DF

For pyspark, dealing with RDDs is way to expensive, so as soon as I changed the piece of code than transforms the DF into an RDD and back to a DF and created some basic DF transformations, the problem was solved.

Cheers